# Derivative of a definite integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.3 or earlier. Fixed in 13.0 or earlier.**

---

The derivation process of a definite integral is as follows:
[image: Integral process]

(* D[Integrate[(1 + t^4)^(-1/2), {t, x^2, x^3}],x]
= (3*x^2)/Sqrt[1 + x^12]-(2*x)/Sqrt[1 + x^8] *)

However, the results obtained by Mathematica are as follows:

```
f[x_] := Integrate[(1 + t^4)^(-1/2), {t, x^2, x^3}];

Assuming[Element[x,Reals], D[f[x],x]]
```

（* (-1)^(1/4) (EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) x^2], -1] -
EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) x^3], -1]) *）

Comment: (1) You didn't take the derivative in your code. (2) A trick to get the answer quickly is to stop `Integrate` from evaluating: `D[Unevaluated@Integrate[(1 + t^4)^(-1/2), {t, x^2, x^3}], x]`

Comment: Thanks! @Michael E2

Comment: Much slower than @MichaelE2 approach but gives same result: `Assuming[Element[x, Reals], Simplify /@ (D[Integrate[(1 + t^4)^(-1/2), {t, x^2, x^3}], x] // Expand)]`

Comment: Thanks! @ Bob Hanlon

Comment: Moreover, `Plot[{(-1)^(
   1/4) (EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) x^2], -1] - 
     EllipticF[I ArcSinh[(-1)^(1/4) x^3], -1]), (3 x^2)/
    Sqrt[1 + x^12] - (2 x)/Sqrt[1 + x^8]}, {x, 0, 1}]` results in different plots.

Comment: What version do you use? OK in 13.0.0 on Windows 10 (see my answer).

Comment: Or do `frule = f -> Function[t, (1 + t^4)^(-1/2)]; 
D[Integrate[f[t], {t, x^2, x^3}], x] /. frule `

Comment: Version 11.3. Thanks! @user64494

Comment: Thanks you! @Akku14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) evaluated before the derivative could be taken, making the output much more complicated. I think the cleanest approach is to use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive), e.g.:

```
D[Inactive[Integrate][(1+t^4)^(-1/2), {t, x^2, x^3}], x]
```

> -((2 x)/Sqrt[1 + x^8]) + (3 x^2)/Sqrt[1 + x^12]

Answer (score 1):

OK in version 13.0.0 on Windows 10

```
D[Integrate[(1 + t^4)^(-1/2), {t, x^2, x^3}], x]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(-1)^( 1/4) ((2 (-1)^(3/4) x)/(Sqrt[1 - I x^4] Sqrt[1 + I x^4]) - ( 3 (-1)^(3/4) x^2)/(Sqrt[1 - I x^6] Sqrt[1 + I x^6])), And[ Or[Im[x] >= 0, Re[x^8 (x - Im[x])^4 (-1 + Im[x])^(-4)] >= -1],  Or[Re[(1 - x)^(-1) x] < -1, Re[(1 - x)^(-1) x] >= 0,  NotElement[(1 - x)^(-1) x, Reals]], Re[x^8] >= -1, Re[x^12] >= -1,  Or[Re[x] > 0,  NotElement[x, Reals]]]]`

Then

```
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[( x (3 x Sqrt[1 + x^8] - 2 Sqrt[1 + x^12]))/Sqrt[(1 + x^8) (1 +  x^12)], Or[x Re[(1 - x)^(-1)] < -1, Re[(1 - x)^(-1)] >= 0,  NotElement[(1 - x)^(-1), Reals]]]`